# sscalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule - cannot invoke main method anymore :(

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to build a new facade that uses a lot of `JSImport` statements. I wanted to put it in a subfolder of a project I am currently working on, to improve it while at it.

Before my root build.sbt looked like this for the scala.js part:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("modules/client"))
      .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSWeb)
      .settings(generalSettings: _*)
      .settings(
        name := "client",
        libraryDependencies += CrossDependencies.scalaTags,
        persistLauncher := true
      )
```

now I added this: `scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule`, which is incompatible with the `persistLauncher` setting, so I removed `persistLauncher := true`

Of course in my view I could no longer just add `client-launcher.js`. So I tried to wrap the main-method call manually, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tld.test.Test().main()
</script>
```

Now, this does **NOT** work **IF** `scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule` is added to my `build.sbt`. If I remove that setting everything works just fine.

This is my Test

```
package tld.test

import org.scalajs.dom
import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp

object Test extends JSApp
{
  import scalatags.JsDom.all._

  def main(): Unit =
  {
    // Add js script dynamically
    val s = script(
      "alert('Hello World!')"
    )
    dom.document.getElementsByTagName("head")(0).appendChild(s.render)
  }
}
```

Now, if I remove that ModuleKind-setting an alert pops up with 'Hello World', but if it's there nope. What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

---

**edit**
After answer from @sjrd I tried the following:
`plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.5.0")
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-web-scalajs-bundler" % "0.5.0")
```

`build.sbt`:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("modules/client"))
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin, ScalaJSWeb) // ScalaJSBundlerPlugin automatically enables ScalaJSPlugin
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "client"
    , libraryDependencies += CrossDependencies.scalaTags
    //, scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule // ScalaJSBundlerPlugin implicitly sets moduleKind to CommonJSModule enables ScalaJSPlugin
  )

lazy val server = (project in file("modules/server"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin)
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "server"
    ,libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      CrossDependencies.scalaTest,
      CrossDependencies.scalactic,
      CrossDependencies.scalaTags,
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0-M1")
    ,scalaJSProjects := Seq(client)
    ,pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline)
    //,pipelineStages := Seq(digest, gzip)
    ,compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalaJSPipeline).value
  )
```

But during compilation I get:

> ERROR in ./fastopt-launcher.js
>   [info] Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /home/sorona/scalajstestbed/modules/client/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/client-fastopt.js in /home/sorona/scalajstestbed/modules/client/target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main

---

**edit**: Solution is to then include `client-fastopt-bundle.js` et voila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the module kind significantly changes the shape of the output file, include its external "specification". In particular, it is not a script that can be embedded in Web page anymore. Instead, it is a CommonJS module.

To be able to include it in a Web page, you will need to *bundle* it. The best way to do so is too use [`scalajs-bundler`](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/).